# Creating a Google Dashboard with multiple Dashboards and Datatables fed from Google Spreadsheets with Queries

Tags: javascript, api, google-visualization

first time posting on here.

I am trying to develop a Google Dashboard, that displays multiple charts. Each chart needs to be fed data from different data-tables. These data-tables are populated from the same Google spreadsheet, via JSON feed. I am producing the data tables by running queries against the Google Spreadsheet, and storing them as variables when Google return the query.

For further complication, I have category filters that need to effect each chart. This is done by creating a dashboard for each separate data-table, like a 'logical' dashboard, aggregating them together, and I am creating category filters on each of them. The first instance of category filter I am putting an event listen on, to affect to other category filters on the other dashboards. That way all the chart are effect by the state changes made on only on category filter.

For proof of concept I am developing the below code, I have run Javascript console and fixed all errors, but I am still getting a blank page.

I hope the above makes sense, thanks in advance for your help.

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Google visualisation demo: chart query controls</title>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // Load the Visualization API and the controls package.
    // Packages for all the other charts you need will be loaded
    // automatically by the system.
    google.load('visualization', '1.1', {'packages':['controls','linechart']});

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    // Declare variables outside of functions.
    var data1;
    var data2;

    function drawVisualization() {

    // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
    var query1 = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0AkjuVAUAbKOZdFM2LTByOVdLMkpFT3FmVTFyOW1jT2c&output=html');

    // Apply query language.
    query1.setQuery('SELECT E,F,I,C, sum(D) group by E,F,I,C');

    // Send the query with a callback function.
    query1.send(Dashboard1);

    // Replace the data source URL on next line with your data source URL.
    var query2 = new google.visualization.Query('http://spreadsheets.google.com/tq?key=0AkjuVAUAbKOZdFM2LTByOVdLMkpFT3FmVTFyOW1jT2c&output=html');

    // Apply query language.
    query2.setQuery('SELECT E,F,I,C, sum(D) group by E,F,I,C');

    // Send the query with a callback function.
    query2.send(Dashboard2);

    // First category filter
    network_filter = createDashboard1();
    network_filter2 = createDashboard2();

    // Second category filter
    introducer_filter = createDashboard1();
    introducer_filter2 = createDashboard2();

    // Third category filter
    business_filter = createDashboard1();
    business_filter2 = createDashboard2();

    // First category filter Event Listener
    google.visualization.events.addListener(network_filter, 'statechange', function() {
        network_filter2.setState(network_filter.getState());
        network_filter2.draw();
    });

    // Second category filter Event Listener
    google.visualization.events.addListener(business_filter, 'statechange', function() {
        business_filter2.setState(business_filter.getState());
        business_filter2.draw();
    });

    // Third category filter Event Listener
    google.visualization.events.addListener(introducer_filter, 'statechange', function() {
        introducer_filter2.setState(introducer_filter.getState());
        introducer_filter2.draw();
    });

    }

    function Dashboard1(response) {
        data1 = response.getDataTable();
        return data1;
        }

    // Everything is loaded. Assemble your dashboard...
    function createDashboard1() {

    // Wrapper for category filter declared in above function
    var networkPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'network_filter',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Main Network',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false    
      }
    }
    });

    // Wrapper for category filter declared in above function
    var businessPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'business_filter',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Business',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false    
      }
    }
    });

    // Wrapper for category filter declared in above function
    var introducerPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'introducer_filter',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Introducer',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false    
      }
    }
    });

    // Chart effected by category filter
    var introducerChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'ColumnChart',
    'containerId': 'introducer_chart',

    'options': {
      'width': 800,
      'height': 200
    },
    'view': {'columns': [2, 4]}
    });

    // Table effected by category filter
    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'table',
    'options': {
      'width': '900px'
    }
    });

    // Bind, glue and draw dashboard
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div')).
        bind(networkPicker, businessPicker).
        bind(businessPicker, introducerPicker).
        bind(introducerPicker, introducerChart).
        bind(introducerPicker, table).
        draw(data1);

        return networkPicker;
        return businessPicker;
        return introducerPicker;
        return data1;
    }

    function Dashboard2(response) {
        data2 = response.getDataTable();
        return data2;
    }

    // Everything is loaded. Assemble your dashboard...
    function createDashboard2() {

    // Wrapper for category filter declared in above function
    var networkPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'network_filter2',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Main Network',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false    
      }
    }
    });

    // Wrapper for category filter declared in above function
    var businessPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'business_filter2',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Business',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false    
      }
    }
    });

    // Wrapper for category filter declared in above function
    var introducerPicker = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
    'containerId': 'introducer_filter2',
    'options': {
      'filterColumnLabel': 'Introducer',
      'ui': {
        'labelStacking': 'vertical',
        'allowTyping': false,
        'allowMultiple': false    
      }
    }
    });

    // PieChart effected by category filter
    var productPie = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
       'chartType':'PieChart',
       'containerId': 'product_pie',
        'options': {'width': 300,'height': 300},
        'view': {'columns': [3, 4]}
    });

    // Table effected by category filter 
    var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Table',
    'containerId': 'table2',
    'options': {
      'width': '900px'
    }
    });

    // Bind, glue and draw dashboard
    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div')).
        bind(networkPicker, businessPicker).
        bind(businessPicker, introducerPicker).
        bind(introducerPicker, productPie).
        bind(introducerPicker, table).
        draw(data2);

        return networkPicker;
        return businessPicker;
        return introducerPicker;
        return data2;
    }

    // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    </script>
</head>
<body>

<!--Div that will hold the dashboard-->
    <div id="dashboard_div">
        <!--Divs that will hold each control and chart-->
        <div id="network_filter"></div>
        <!--Display none because its managed by event listener-->
        <div id="network_filter2" style="display:none"></div>
        <div id="business_filter"></div>
        <!--Display none because its managed by event listener-->
        <div id="business_filter2" style="display:none"></div>
        <div id="introducer_filter"></div>
        <!--Display none because its managed by event listener-->
        <div id="introducer_filter2" style="display:none"></div>
        <div id="introducer_chart"></div>
        <div id="product_pie"></div>
        <div id="table"></div>
        <div id="table2"></div>
    </div>

<body>
</html>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing it like this.  My recommendation would be to take one chart, and use MVC design to expand that chart into the additional charts.  For instance, you would have separate controller actions and views pertaining to each chart and then have another view that combines all the charts on one page.  This creates a separation of concerns, which will be helpful later.

Comment: If you're using the same data for both dashboards (which you seem to be), and you're using the same filters for both data tables (which you seem to be), then you are unecessarily complicating your code. I suggest a single query to a single datatable which is directly filtered by a single set of controls. You can then clone the datatable to create two separate charts, which are all part of a single dashboard element. Controls alter original datatable, listeners take the new datatable, clone and modify as needed, dashboard puts them all together.